# Is “proceeded” used correctly in“how this case proceeded”?

Tags: sentence-construction

Is below sentence is grammatically correct?

> How this rape case proceeded very differently from the other rape cases.

It’s from [Important lessons to be learnt: How the Kathua rape case proceeded very differently from the Unnao rape case](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/blogs/toi-edit-page/important-lessons-to-be-learnt-how-the-kathua-rape-case-proceeded-very-differently-from-the-unnao-rape-case/)

According to me “proceeded” has been used incorrectly in above sentence. It should be “*was proceeded*”.

“Proceeded” is transitive verb. Judge need to proceed the case in court.

Is there any article where I can read about when it is mandatory to use is/was in the English?

Answer (score 2):

For context, the indicated statement is a headline from a Times of India [article](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/blogs/toi-edit-page/important-lessons-to-be-learnt-how-the-kathua-rape-case-proceeded-very-differently-from-the-unnao-rape-case/), which reads:

> **Important lessons to be learnt: How the Kathua rape case proceeded very differently from the Unnao rape case**

In this case, the sentence *is* correct, if a little awkward.  The verb **[to proceed](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proceed)** means (among other definitions) *to go on in an orderly regulated way*.  I have only scan-read the article but, from what I can tell, it attempts to describe differences in the way two cases were tried in court.

You may be mistaking the verb **to proceed**, with another **[to precede](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/precede)**, which means *to be earlier than*.

If the article was describing the order in which two cases were tried, rather than the processes by which they were tried, then you could say that one case *was preceded* by the other.